# Weak "assign" references rather than singletons

Tags: objective-c

I have many objects reference the same class of stored data. In previous programs, I've used singletons, but am trying to abandon that practice and only use them as a last resort when necessary, mainly due to the bad reputation they have (and indeed I've abused them in the past).

But I'm wondering just how much of an advantage my new technique is. I'm simply creating weak references to the same set of data so a bunch of classes point to the same memory to pull data as needed. Such as:

`@property (nonatomic, assign) MyDataClass*mydata;`

In a custom `init` of the class, I pass a reference as a method parameter, then the `property` assigns to this reference.

Is this a valid, acceptable way to do things? I'm having trouble finding much of an organizational advantage to doing this over using singletons.

Comment: Why is this `assign` rather than `retain`?

Comment: because it is a weak reference and the class does not own the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern you use is just fine, eventually this pattern is used in all standard C++ programs without reference counting or other advanced memory management tools. The only thing you have to ensure that your object hierarchy strictly respects the weakness of the reference i.e. the dependency of the object having the reference towards the object that is behind that reference. In other words, you always have to ensure that the owner of the reference is deleted *before* the reference and you have to do ensure manually since you're not using the reference counting.

This means more responsibility for you, the programmer as you always have to have total control over the lifetime of your objects. It is quite easy to make mistake with your pattern since you can't know from the code having the weak reference whether the original object still exist or it is deleted. You have to ensure this with your design pattern.

For this reason I don't suggest to "mix" the two approaches, i.e. having weak references to an object that might be freed out-of-control by a `retain` type property (when the value of the property changes from your object), an `autorelease` or by `ARC`.

Reference counting was introduced to take away this responsibility from the programmer and make it easier to write safe code. Your pattern is fine, it is used by millions of C++ programs but you have to be conscious of your responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, you should only use a singleton class for objects where it wouldn't make sense for more than one of them to exist. Otherwise, it's best to avoid them because they introduce coupling: every class that uses the singleton ends up tightly coupled to the singleton.

Passing references to stuff is fine. They don't have to be weak references of course, except where necessary in order to avoid retain cycles.

If you do find that you're passing the same objects around between a large number of classes, you might want to consider thinking about division of responsibility and restructuring your app.

Answer (score 0):

Retain/Assign and using Singletons aren't mutually exclusive patterns. I wouldn't be so hesitant against the singleton, I was at first when I started iOS.

Coming from being a java web apps developer, Singletons were bad due to the tight coupling, and especially because if you wanted to distribute your application across a load balancer / (cloud now)... then your singleton would become a bottleneck - and wouldn't be easily scalable.

There were also problems with Unit testing with Singletons, and having to reset it's state during tests, or even trying to mock it out.

However, in Objective-C and iOS development - I'm not really seeing that many disadvantages to singletons. Your app isn't going to be scaled, and the sdk is already littered with singletons  to hinder your unit tests.